# Maven Surefire plugin executes JUnit 4 tests, even though the JUnit Vintage Engine is not in Maven the project

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Maven project that contains both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests.

I am using the Maven Surefire plugin in version `3.0.0-M07`. The following relevant dependencies are available in the Maven dependency tree (I checked with `mvn dependency:tree`):

- `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test`
- `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test`
- `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test`
- `junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test`

[According to the JUnit 5 documentation, the JUnit Vintage Engine needs to be present to execute JUnit 4 tests.](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5)

However, the Maven Surefire plugin executes both the JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests.

Why is the Maven Surefire plugin able to execute JUnit 4 tests, even though there is no dependency on the JUnit Vintage Engine in my Maven project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `junit-jupiter-api` maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin loads the `junit-vintage-engine` automatically and executes JUnit 4 based tests.

The correct way is to use the `junit-jupiter-engine` instead of `junit-jupiter-api`. This is explained in the [surefire documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)

An deep explanation is available [here](https://youtu.be/Xy6m9rNYBhc).

Comment: I read the doc differently: It’s the dependency to junit:junit which will automatically load the vintage engine.